# change action link on views exposed form

Tags: 7, views

I have created a views exposed form. How can I change the action link, or the "Submit" button.

I use Drupal 7.

Comment: Change it how, wording / make it auto submit / style / markup?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the value of the submit button inside the view: 
Advanced -> Exposed From -> Exposed form style -> Settings -> Submit button text. 
From http://drupal.org/node/109604:
The documentation for Views 2 and Views 3 for Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 is contained within [Views module!](http://drupal.org/project/views)
Install the [Advanced Help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module to access it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal form, so you can change what you want with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Beware though : if you change the structure (vs presentation) of the form, you'll probably run into problems.